# Test asp (Classic) querystring field between 2 mysql databse fields

Tags: mysql, sql, vbscript, asp-classic

Ok, I have a web form (classic asp / vbscript) where a user enters serial numbers in ranges, FirstSerial and LastSerial only. The in-between numbers are not entered. This form is submitted, (querystring) and tested against a mysql db.

What I cannot seem to do is get my SQL correct when checking for duplicates when loading new serial numbers.

Lets say for example the last range entered and saved to the db was:
(These are both in the same table)

First: 0115323704
Last:  0115323715

Next time as user tries to load new serials, but forgets about the last range entered. I need to make sure that the FIRST, LAST and any number between have not been entered previously.

i.e. entering 0115323704, 0115323715 or 0115323711 would flag a warning
0115323716 would be accepted !

If they have, flag up a warning message to try again, otherwise allow the new (non duplicate) serials to be loaded and continue.

At present, I am only testing against the FIRST & LAST, but I need to have everything in-between tested also.

```
JobSerial = Table
PSL_F_Serial & PSL_L_Serial = Stored Serial numbers
FirstSerial & LastSerial = Range submitted by user
```

This sql works, but I need it upgraded and cannot get it working as required, so any help would be appreciated :-)

```
uSQL = "SELECT * FROM JobSerial WHERE (PSL_F_Serial = " & FirstSerial & ") or (PSL_L_Serial = " & LastSerial & ") or (PSL_F_Serial = " & LastSerial & ") or (PSL_L_Serial = " & FirstSerial & ");"
```

Look forward to hearing from you

Comment: What is the data type of PSL_F_Serial and PSL_L_Serial in the db ?

Comment: Hi, they are both 'VarChar' data type in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If they are varchar then you need to add quotes.

uSQL = "SELECT * FROM JobSerial WHERE (PSL_F_Serial = '" & FirstSerial & "') or (PSL_L_Serial = '" & LastSerial & "') or (PSL_F_Serial = '" & LastSerial & "') or (PSL_L_Serial = '" & FirstSerial & "');"

Comment: Thanks, but this is just enhancing the code I have currently, not testing for serials between the range .... I think ? I add the extra comments anyway to see what happens and report back.

Comment: Yep, as expected, adding the extra quotes makes no difference to the results found.

If the First & Last serials entered previously are:

0115324120 to 0115324143

Then I need the system to tell me that both these numbers and the ones in-between 0115324121 to 0115324142 have been used before!!

This is what I cannot get to work correctly .... please help, thanks